# How to remove System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.Part

Tags: web-part

I am trying to remove some WebParts from a page in my site collection. Normally I can do this with SPLimitedWebPartManager.DeleteWebPart(webPart) however, that will not delete System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.Part nor can I cast it to a WebPart object (it returns null).

Currently I am just setting visible attribute to false, but ideally I would like to delete it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you able to remove the webpart using `?contents=1` query string?

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you mean by that, but I tried your post below and it worked.

Comment: If you append `?contents=1` to a portal page url (i.e. `http://site/default.aspx?contents=1`), the Maintenance page will be shown, and you'll be able to delete webparts through GUI. Although the problem is solved, this is a quite useful notion anyway :)

Comment: System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.Part is an abstract class and the base class of all webparts, you can't have an actual webpart on a page with that object type. Or did you mean "webparts derived from that class"? I'm confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to get the WebPart object by [indexer of the WebParts collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.splimitedwebpartcollection.item.aspx), and then pass it to DeleteWebPart method without any additional casting.

For example:

```
manager.DeleteWebPart(manager.WebParts[7]);
```

The indexer returns strongly-typed System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart object, at least as it goes from the MSDN documentation, so this should work (however, didn't test it myself).

Comment: I tried your idea and it worked.